# Python Selenium Element Not Interactable, Element is hidden

Tags: python, selenium, automation, webautomation

I'm trying to click on a button that but it seems to be not ineractable.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
    driver.get(k['product_url'])
    driver.maximize_window()
    
    
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_jstl__header_r"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/button').click()
    
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.shoppingexpress.com.au/_mycart');")
    time.sleep(5)

    
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Checkout Now"]').click()
    
    print("Element is visible? " + str(elem.is_displayed()))
    
    driver.execute_script('$("button").click();') 

    opts.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
```

Photo of inspect:

[image: PHOTO OF INSPECT]

Please help I think the button is hidden, although I can't seem to access it

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting it from the title, and doesn't hurt to add explicit waits either:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.shoppingexpress.com.au/_mycart');")

# Wait for button to be clickable
elemWait = EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@title="Checkout Now"]'))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(elemWait)

# Click button
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@title="Checkout Now"]').click()
```

If that doesn't work, it could be that it is still focused on the previous tab. So you might have to switch to the one you just opened (although I didn't have to in Firefox):

```
# Switch to current tab
handles = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[len(handles) - 1])
```